# Contexto para Glide en un adapter

Tags: android, android-studio

Encontré un ejemplo de flexbox para android, ahora estoy intentando cargar una imagen con glide desde un adapter, sin embargo tengo un error de contexto.

```
class DivLikeAdapter(private val mItems: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DivLikeAdapter.DivItemViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DivLikeAdapter.DivItemViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        return DivItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    ...
    inner class DivItemViewHolder constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    (itemView) {
        //private val text: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text)
        private val img: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)

        fun onBind(position: Int) {
            //text.text = mItems[position]

            Glide.with(MainActivity())   //AQUI
                    .load(mItems[position]).into(img)
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com99.example.gal.flexboxlayout, PID: 23523
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:118)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:188)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:774)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:826)
        at com99.example.gal.flexboxlayout.DivLikeAdapter$DivItemViewHolder.onBind(DivLikeAdapter.kt:40)
        at com99.example.gal.flexboxlayout.DivLikeAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DivLikeAdapter.kt:24)
        at com99.example.gal.flexboxlayout.DivLikeAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DivLikeAdapter.kt:15)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        ....
```

El error es de contexto al parecer, aunque no estoy seguro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es bastante obvio. En esta linea estás creando manualmente una activity: `Glide.with(MainActivity())`. Nunca hagas eso, las activities deben ser creadas por el sistema. Jamás crees una de esa forma. Cuando necesites un context puedes obtenerlo de cualquier view. En tu caso sería así:

```
Glide.with(img.context)
```

Pero nisiquiera necesitas hacer eso porque el método `Glide.with` también acepta que le pases una view. Dale cualquier view y él internamente obtendrá el context.

```
Glide.with(img)
```

Comment: Funciona, también probé con  itemView y da el mismo resultado.
Entonces ambos están realizando lo mismo o ahi algo que se deba tener en cuenta?

Comment: Es que no estabas tan lejos de lograrlo. En realidad si debes pasarle la mainActivity. El error fue que estabas creando una nueva en lugar de usar la que ya estaba creada. Lo que devuelve el método `view.context` es la activity a la que pertenece esa vista (`Activity` es una subclase de `Context`). Dado que ambas views pertenecen a la misma activity, puedes pasarle cualquiera.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración